# selenium does not loop trough all credentials, gives Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

when I try to automate a website by using a loop structure, first iteration runs but second iteration does not and gives .NoSuchElementException error

I have already tried to enter the credentials without loop, still same issue, when the page logs out after first iteration, webelements can not be located. I already checked them and they are still same, not dynamic

public static void TestTitle() throws Exception {

```
    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();

    //user credentials in array
    String credentials[][] = {{"user39", "UserUser123"}, {"storemanager77", "UserUser123"}, {"salesmanager140", "UserUser123"}};

    driver.get("http://qa2.*******.com/user/login");

    for (int i = 0; i < credentials.length; i++) {
            //enters the credential to the website by pulling from the 2d array and logins to the app
            driver.findElement(By.name("prependedInput")).sendKeys(credentials[i][0]);
            driver.findElement(By.id("prependedInput2")).sendKeys(credentials[i][1]);
            driver.findElement(By.id("_submit")).click();
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            //finds the dropdown menu and goes to the configuration
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"user-menu\"]/a")).click();
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Configuration")).click();
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            driver.navigate().refresh();

            //gets the page title
            String pageTitle = driver.getTitle();
           //gets the profile name
            String profileTitle=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='javascript: void(0);']")).getText();
            //compare page title and profile name
            if(pageTitle.contains(profileTitle)){
                System.out.println("Passed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed");
            }

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            //goes to the profile and logs out from the app
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"user-menu\"]/a")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
            //clears the login credentials from previous login
            driver.findElement(By.id("prependedInput")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("prependedInput2")).clear();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

    }
}
```

I expect my loop works, logs into the website by entering the credentials to the website than log out, and then enter the next credentials to the same website and logs out

Comment: Please provide the full exception, it will tell us which line of code is causing the error.  It's most likely a wait error.

Comment: Here is the error code Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: The command failed because the specified element is obscured.

Comment: That means that there is an element in front of the element that you are trying to click.  One possible fix is to put in an explicit wait for it to become clickable, however that assume that the element obscuring the element you are trying to click will be moved out of the way in due course.